# Selenium Calender UI Handling

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, calendar

Iam learning calender UI handling concept in selenium but stuck 
**Code 1 :**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

enter code here

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class CalenderUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\sumit goyal\\Downloads\\chromedriver_latest\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.airindia.in/");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.bookFlight")).click(); //CALENDER Resides inside it

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Departing']")).click(); // will open calendar POPUPmenu

        WebElement cal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]")); //restricting scope

        while(!(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] span:nth-child(2)")).getText().equals("2021")))

        {
            cal.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-handler='next']")).click(); //will click on next button until 2021 arrives

        }

    }

}
```

after running code i got this error : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Every Selector seems correct I checked it iam not getting why its failing

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if a DOM operation happening on the page is temporarily causing the element to be inaccessible. To allow for those cases, you need try to re locate the element again inside the loop.

Replace below code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Departing']")).click(); // will open calendar POPUPmenu
while (!(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='ui-datepicker-title'] span:nth-child(2)")).getText().equals("2021"))) {
    WebElement cal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]")); //restricting scope
    cal.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-handler='next']")).click(); //will click on next button until 2021 arrives
}
```

Comment: @Sumit Goyal, is this answer resolved your problem ? If yes then accept it by click tick mark on answer below vote count so it can be helpful for others. Still have query then feel free to ask ?